# How can I add meta tags for sharing a particular link in React.js?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router, meta-tags, react-helmet

Say, I have an online shop application built with `React.js` and I want to customize the look of the URL that is shared on social media (e.g. add a description and an image) using HTML meta tags. Besides, I want the route of particular product (e.g. `https://www.mywebsite.com/product/<productId>`) to preview the **appropriate** picture and description of it, so it is not acceptable to just include the meta tags in the `index.html`.

I have tried to use `react-helmet` and other packages that are used for adding meta tags, but they didn't help. I guess, it is because `react-helmet` adds the meta tags after the app renders and not just when the URL is shared somewhere.

Is the only solution to this problem to use server-side rendering or there is a way to handle it from front-end only?

Comment: This is usually why Server Side Rendering (SSR) is needed. At bare minimum you could use [ReactDOMServer](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html). That being said, this is precisely why libraries such as [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) or [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/) exist.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Thanks for your response. Actually, I have been thinking of creating an API endpoint that would render the appropriate meta tags for a particular product using EJS templates, just wanted to ensure that there is no way to handle this without back-end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the below example step by step to do the same

**Step 1 – Install below command Using NPM**

```
npm install react-meta-tags --save
```

Note: You can also achieve this using [React Helmet (a third party library)](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet)

**Step 2 – Use MetaTag Component in your class Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import MetaTags from 'react-meta-tags';

class Component1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
          <MetaTags>
            <title>Your Page 1</title>
            <meta name="description" content="Your description here.." />
            <meta property="og:title" content="Your App" />
            <meta property="og:image" content="Your path/to/image.jpg" />
          </MetaTags>
          <div className="content"> Your Content here... </div>
        </div>
      )
  }
}
```

Note: Define id on tags so if you navigate to other page, older meta tags will be replaced/update by new ones.

**Step 3 - ReactTitle Component:**

If you just want to add title on a page you can use ReactTitle instead.

```
import React from 'react';
import {ReactTitle} from 'react-meta-tags';

class Component2 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
          <ReactTitle title="Your Page 2"/>
          <div className="content"> Your Page 2 Content </div>
        </div>
      )
  }
}
```

**The Server Usage Example:**

```
import MetaTagsServer from 'react-meta-tags/server';
import {MetaTagsContext} from 'react-meta-tags';

/* Import other required modules */
/*  some serve specific code */

app.use((req, res) => {
  //make sure you get a new metatags instance for each request
  const metaTagsInstance = MetaTagsServer();

  //react router match
  match({
    routes, location: req.url
  }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    let reactString;

    try{
      reactString = ReactDomServer.renderToString(
      <Provider store={store}> 
      {/*** If you are using redux ***/}
      {/* You have to pass extract method through MetaTagsContext so it can catch meta tags */}

        <MetaTagsContext extract = {metaTagsInstance.extract}>
          <RouterContext {...renderProps}/>
        </MetaTagsContext>
      </Provider>
      );
    }
    catch(e){
      res.status(500).send(e.stack);
      return;
    }

    //get all title and metatags as string
    const meta = metaTagsInstance.renderToString();

    //append metatag string to your layout
    const htmlStr = (`
      <!doctype html>
      <html lang="en-us">
        <head>
          <meta charSet="utf-8"/>
          ${meta}
        </head>
        <body>
          <div id="content">
            ${reactString}
          </div>
        </body>
      </html>  
    `);

    res.status(200).send(layout);
  });
});
```

As per the above code we have to do following for server rendering options

1. Import MetaTagsServer form server
2. Import MetaTagsContext form server
3. Create a new instance of MetaTagsServer
4. Wrap your component inside MetaTagsContext and pass extract method as props
5. Extract Meta string using renderToString of MetaTagsServer instance
6. Append Meta string to your html template.

**JSX Layout:**

You might also be using React to define your layout, in which case you can use getTags method from metaTagsInstance. The layout part of above server side example will look like this.

```
//get all title and metatags as React elements
const metaTags = metaTagsInstance.getTags();

//append metatag string to your layout
const layout = (
  <html lang="en-us">
    <head>
      <meta charSet="utf-8"/>
      {metaTags}
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="app" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: reactString}} />
    </body>
  </html>  
);

const htmlStr = ReactDomServer.renderToString(layout);

res.status(200).send(htmlStr);
```

Comment: How does the last example JSX Layout work? You need to load the html DOM first where you load you JS files to implement react. I'm not criticizing, I had the same idea. I'm just curious