# How can i add meta tags for preview of a page in my blog react redux project

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, meta-tags

I created a blog project in react with redux

my blog details component is this

```
export class BlogDetails extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    home: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    const { seoName } = this.props.match.params;
    let routeLength = seoName.length;
    let seoNameLength = routeLength - 28;
    // let routeParams = route.params.id;
    let seoNames = seoName.substring(0, seoNameLength - 1);
    let blogUUID = seoName.substring(seoNameLength, routeLength);
    this.props.actions.loadBlog({ blogUUID });
  };

  render() {
    const { blog } = this.props.home;
    return (
      <main>
        <section
          className="section parallax effect-section"
          style={{ backgroundImage: 'url(../web/img/bg-2.jpg)' }}
        >
          <div className="mask dark-bg opacity-8"></div>
          <div className="container position-relative">
            <div className="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
              <div className="col-lg-10 text-center">
                <h6 className="white-color-light font-w-500">We are awesome designer</h6>
                <h1 className="display-4 white-color m-0px">{blog ? blog.title : ''}</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section className="section gray-bg">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-lg-12 p-40px-r lg-p-15px-r md-m-15px-tb">
                {blog ? (
                  <div className="article box-shadow">
                    <div className="article-img">
                      <img
                        src={
                          blog.blogPreviewKeyName
                            ? `${process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_PREFIX}${blog.blogPreviewKeyName}`
                            : '../web/img/blog-1.jpg'
                        }
                        width="1066px"
                        height="300px"
                        title=""
                        alt=""
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="article-title">
                      <h2>{blog.title}</h2>
                      <div className="media">
                        <div className="media-body">
                          <h6>{convertBlogDetailTimeStampToDate(blog.dateCreated)}</h6>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div
                      className="article-content"
                      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                        __html: DOMPurify.sanitize(blog.description),
                      }}
                    ></div>
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  ''
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </main>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    home: state.home,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators({ ...actions }, dispatch),
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BlogDetails);
```

and URL of my blog details is **http://localhost:8075/blogs/10-reasons-to-use-nuxt-js-for-your-next-web-application-xwnx0gm7cl221l51536o63zy64yy**

Now I want to add meta tags in this BlogDetails component

Which way is more efficient

1 - By using any npm react library

2 - Or without any library (if possible)

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to add meta tags is through server side rendering.

Doing it on client could result in a lot of issues with regards to SEO. When you add meta tags on client side, some of the search engine crawlers wouldn't be able to read meta tags because they get render on client through javascript.

Having said that, there are two ways to add meta tags in the React app.

**On the server through server side rendering (SSR).**

This is the most effective way and doesn't necessarily require any library since, you will simply be hydrating the html content on server and you can just add you meta tags as well.
For SSR though, going with [next.js](https://nextjs.org/) is recommended.

**[react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) on client side.**

If you don't want to get into all that SSR stuff then `helmet` is the best way to inject meta tags. It's super easy to use and most of the things are configured already.

It could have some drawbacks as not all the crawlers would be able to read those meta tags.

When you add meta tags through `helmet`, they will not be visible in the `view source code`.

```
<Helmet>
    <meta charSet="utf-8" />
    <title>My Title</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="example.com" />
</Helmet>
```

Comment: Did it not work at all or is it not working in some specific use case? @chaitanyagupta

Comment: it is not work at all when i am inpsecting elements all the tags are there but while sharing url nothing works and also in view page source none of my meta properties present

Comment: ``react-helment`` adds meta tags on the clients side, which means wile sharing URLs or doing a view source, you wouldn't be able to see those meta tags.

Comment: In that case, you would need to go with the SSR. That's the only to solve this problem.

Comment: Any other solution?

Comment: As far as I know, from only client side, it's not possible. You would need to involve server in one way or other.
Here's an interesting thread worth reading https://www.indiehackers.com/post/solved-react-app-with-dynamic-meta-tags-without-ssr-cdda6da385

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60045028/how-can-i-add-meta-tags-for-sharing-a-particular-link-in-react-js
please see this post from 3rd step there is a server related settings 
But i dont in which file i write this code